# Dynamically created checkbox click event selecting the whole row instead of only the check box in a jquery datatable. Why is that?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, datatables

I have added a new row in my jquery datatable with html content(checkbox input) on some event as:

```
$("#btn").on( 'click', function (){
    $('#mytable').DataTable().row.add([data[0],data[1],"<td><input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"\" /></td>"]).draw();
}
```

Now, when I click on the 'checkbox' from the dynamically created row, the whole row is getting triggered along with the checkbox. Hence, the below even is not getting triggered:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on( 'click', function (e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

But in turn triggers this event:

```
$("#mytable tbody").on( 'click', 'tr', function (){
   $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
 ....
}
```

Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: Try doing a `.not` on your last snippet, as I believe it will be triggered when *anything* inside the element is clicked. `$("#mytable tbody").not('input[type="checkbox"]').on...`. (Posted as a comment as I believe better answers may be available. See [Rory McCrossan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40025097/2026606) below.)

Comment: if you want those checkboxes on all rows is typically better to use rendering callbacks in plugin to generate them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't stop propagation on a delegated event handler as it has already propagated through the DOM before it's handled.

Alternatively you can inspect the `event.target` in the `tr` click handler and not do any work if it was the checkbox that was clicked:

```
$("#mytable tbody").on('click', 'tr', function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'input')
        return;

    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
})
```

Comment: don't think you will prevent click propagating though

Comment: @charlietfl you're right. Brain fart. That's enough SO for today :)

Comment: Works perfectly :)

Comment: Code is:                                                                                      if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'input'){
   $('#mytable').DataTable().row( this ).deselect();
   return;
  }